# Electrodes geometry to obtain a uniform electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

It is known that a parallel plate capacitor produces an uniform electric field in the space between its electrodes. However, the field is only approximately uniform near the electrodes (border effects).

My intuition suggests that if we curve the electrodes only near the border, the field will be more uniform with respect to the case where the electrodes are perfectly flat. When I say that a field $\mathbf A$ is more uniform than another $\mathbf B$ I mean that the field $\mathbf A$, at a certain position, has a smaller angle with respect to a fixed direction in space.

Fix an orthogonal coordinate system with the $y$ axis perpendicular to the plates and the $x$ axis parallel to the plates.
I am interested in fields which are only approximately uniform, that is the angle with respect to the $\hat y$ direction must be less than a certain value $\theta$ only for the points lying in the volume bounded by the electrodes.
Consider a function $\sigma(x)$ describing the profile of the electrodes.
The plates are symmetric: that is $\sigma(x) = \sigma(-x)$.
Given the symmetry it is sufficient to study the system composed by only one electrode and an infinite ground plane positioned at the center of the capacitor.
Given a certain distance from the electrode how can I choose the profile $\sigma(x)$ in order to obtain a field more uniform than the field generated by a flat plate capacitor?

Obviously this can be verified solving with FEMs the Laplace's equation for the electrodes configuration but I am interested in analytical solutions since I have to test many configurations.

I guess that, for a fixed quote $y$ with respect to an electrode (with $y < d/2$ and $d$ the distance between the center of the two plates), the more you move near to the border the more the field increases its angle with respect to the $\hat y$ direction.
Based on this, maybe I can set up a functional in order to find the electrodes profile that minimize the angle with respect to the $\hat y$ direction.
I search also for solution based on this type of reasoning.

Comment: I asked a possibly related question [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2868746/charge-density-of-charged-conductor-with-flat-side)

Comment: You say "points lying in the volume bounded by the electrodes" . [This paper](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/jmoea/v10n1/08.pdf) , Figure 7 shows that the angle becomes large near the edges, depending on how sharp the corner is.